# Problem to autocomplete JQueryUI+PHP+MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server

I keep practicing in PHP programming with MSQQL, only now, I want to generate a "textbox" with "autocomplete" to perform searches, I already get the data that I want to show according to the search criteria, but just when I try to return it by the "json_encode", it disappears and does not I see where I can follow up ...

This es mi code to "JQueryUI":

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#seeker').typeahead({
                source: function(query, result) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"appadmin_search.php",
                        method:"POST",
                        data:{query:query},
                        dataType:"json",
                        success:function(data) {
                            result($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return item;
                            }));
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is my PHP Code (appadmin_search.php):

```
<?php

    include('appadminps_internal_h.php');

    $employed = Employed::findAll();
    $return_arr = array();
    // $search = $_GET['term'];
    $search = $_POST['query'];

    $return_arr = Employed::seekerEmploy($search);
    /* $result = $employed::query($query); */
    $a = 0;
    $newArr[] = Employed::utf8_encode(array_values($return_arr));

    // return json_encode(array_values($return_arr),  JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    // echo json_encode($newArr,  JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    //No show errors
    $error = json_last_error();
    //Return Nothing!!!
    var_dump($newArr, $error === JSON_ERROR_UTF8);
    //No printing!!!!!
    print_r($newArr);

    // echo json_encode($newArr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    //On this line dissapear everything!!!!
    echo json_encode($newArr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

Please, somebody to help me??? Thanks a lot for everything.

Best Regards.

Oscar.

Comment: as far as I see from your code (your comments) - `var_dump($newArr);` does not print out any data? then json_encode will not be able to write out json if there is nothing available ;) - for more debugging, can you just do `echo "New Arr: "; var_dump($newArr); die();` and post the output

Comment: Sorry Evil_skunk, I had problems to show me the content of the 'json', only through a function that I found on this site was how I could visualize .script type='text/javascript'&gt; console.log('Debug Objects: Test' ); &lt;/script&gt;[
    {
        "value": 41,
        "label": "Becerra Miranda Angel"
    },
    {
        "value": 50,
        "label": "Barrera Cruz Luis Enrique"
    },
    {
        "value": 65,
        "label": "Balderas Sustaita Veronica"
    },
    {
        "value": 33,
        "label": "Bustamante Arredondo Brenda"
    }